# Clarifying Rust's ownership rules

Tags: rust

I'm reading Rust Programming Language book and would like to clarify following Listing 4.5 in [Return Values and Scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#return-values-and-scope) section:

```
fn main() {
   let s1 = String::from("hello");
   let (s2, len) = calculate_length(s1);
   println!("The length of '{}' is {}.", s2, len);
}
fn calculate_length(s: String) -> (String, usize) {
   let length = s.len(); // len() returns the length of a String
   (s, length)
}
```

If I use:

```
fn calculate_length(s: String) -> (String, usize) {
   (s, s.len())
}
```

then I'm getting:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `s`
  --> guessing_game/src/main.rs:46:9
   |
43 | fn calculate_length(s: String) -> (String, usize) {
   |                     - move occurs because `s` has type `String`, which does not  implement the `Copy` trait
...
46 |     (s, s.len())
   |      -  ^ value borrowed here after move
   |      |
   |      value moved here
```

At the same time if I swap values in returning tuple to `(s.len(), s)` (in `calculate_length` function) and rewrite `main` caller accordingly, it compiles without errors.

Intuitively I understand this borrowing error (and how to fix it), but could somebody clarify/explain this behavior "more formally"?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're searching for, it sounds like you already understand what's going on. When a variable has been moved, you can't use it anymore. You're constructing a tuple, then `s` is moved, then after that you attempt to call `len()` on it. You can't because `s` has already been moved.

Comment: Maybe the OP is asking if the order of evaluation of the values in a tuple is well defined. The answer is that yes, the values in a tuple are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: It would certainly be nice if rust could evaluate tuples in multiple passes, but finding the ordering of tuple elements that allows code to compile (performing moves last) sounds NP-hard

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys! @vallentin, yes - I'm looking for some explanation why moving is performed if String value is used at first place while tuple construction, since this construction seems to be an "atomic" operation

Answer (score 2):

> since this construction seems to be an "atomic" operation

*Constructing a tuple* is “atomic”, but *evaluating an expression* is not. In general, expressions can contain arbitrary side effects in any part of them, so the order of evaluation of sub-expressions can affect the semantics of the program. Some languages leave it partly unspecified, but in Rust, the evaluation order is always left-to-right.

So, evaluating `(s, s.len())` consists of the following steps:

1. Evaluate the first subexpression, `s`. Since `s` is a type that is not `Copy`, this moves the value out of the variable `s`.
2. Evaluate the second subexpression, `s.len()`. (This is an error since `s` is already moved.)
3. Construct the tuple from the value of the first subexpression and the value of the second subexpression.

In this case, looking at the program we can see that it would not have any undesirable consequences to reorder the two subexpression evaluations, but Rust's evaluation order does not have any special cases for different types of expressions.

(The *optimizer* will perform lots of transformations on this code, in particular making nearly all “moves” not involve any memory copying or other actual CPU operations, but it would be very hard to program Rust if the validity of a program depended on the optimizer's choices.)